# How to find if a Wordpress Hook is valid

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hook

I found an interesting blog post from 2015 with the following containing the "single-{$type}_template" hook:

```
add_filter( 'single-hats_template', function( $template ) [
    if ( ! $template ) {
        $template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/default-hats-single.php';
    }
    
    return $template;
});
```

https://wpshout.com/hacking-the-wordpress-template-hierarchy/

That would be perfect for me as I am writing a plugin that only needs to override the template for a certain type of post.

However, I added a filter for this hook, added a breakpoint and got nothing. I couldn't find this hook in any documentation and I wonder if its since been removed?

- I searched the source code, but couldn't find it being called.
- I checked the global $wp_filter in the debugger and it wasn't listed.

is there a definitive way to check if a hook exists?

I am using Wordpress Version  5.6.1

Comment: Why does a [regular wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) template structure cannot be used?

Comment: Share a [minimal version of your plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you figure out what's going on. Without seeing the actual code we can only take guesses.